# How can I create a lambda function from an Elastic Container Registry image using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecr

I have created this lambda function:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async event => {

    const body =
        message: "Hello"
    };

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };

};
```

I have created a Docker image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-nodejs:12
COPY app.js package*.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "app.lambdaHandler" ]
```

and I have pushed it to ECR. Now, I want to create a lambda function that runs it.

I have tried with this command:

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name greeting --role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-role --code ImageUri=xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/greeting:latest
```

and I get this error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the
> CreateFunction operation: Runtime and Handler are mandatory parameters
> for functions created with deployment packages.

It makes no sense because it's a Docker image based lambda function so that parameters shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Do you have up to date awscli? Looks like that feature is only a day old.

Comment: Yes, I have version 2.1.6 installed, which is the latest one. Yep, AWS announced this yesterday...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seemed to work for me. You need to to remove handler, runtime and be sure to specify the package type as Image, and

```
aws lambda create-function  \
--function-name greeting  \
--role  arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-role \
--code ImageUri=xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/greeting:latest \
--package-type Image
```

(AWS Cli version 2.1.7)

Comment: I've done a basic [hello world example](https://code.mendhak.com/lambda-docker-hello-world/) for this in case it helps; I needed it because the CLI lambda docs was too poor and docker-in-Lambda announcement page was too overwhelming.

Comment: You must use AWS Cli version 2.x (1.x does not have the support) and you do not need to add --handler or --runtime attributes.

Answer (score 1):

your create function looks like the below:

```
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name greeting \
  --role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-role \
  --code ImageUri=xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/greeting:latest
```

From the error, you need to specify handler and runtime:

```
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name greeting \
  --runtime nodejs12.x
  --handler lambdaHandler
  --role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/my-role \
  --code ImageUri=xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/greeting:latest
```

this is all pretty new and "feels" like it shouldn't be required bc the container definition defines it...

I wonder if lambda requires [package-type](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html) to be set to obtains these values.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I get a `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Please provide a source for function code.`  I've double checked against the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html) and syntax seems fine.

Comment: did you happen to add `package-type`?